# Publishing immutable

Tags: java, concurrency

Immutable objects can be published through any mechanism-Effectively immutable objects must be safely published(static initialization,volatile etc) - 'Java Concurrency in  practice'.

```
class A{//immutable
    final int i;
    a(int i){
        this.i=i;
    }
    public int getI(){
        return i;
    }
} 

class B{
    A a=null;
    public A getA(){
       if(a==null){ 
           a= new A(10);
       }
       return a;
   }
}
```

If instance of B is shared between threads;wouldn't there be a possibility of a partially constructed  A leaking out - though it is immutable.
Or have I understood this wrong?

Comment: There are only two possibilities: 1) a is null 2) a is fully constructed

Comment: Can you please make sure that the code compiles first?

Comment: Let us assume A to have a much more intensive construction than this.As far as I recall construction itself is not an atomic operation.

Comment: you are right, but assignment to instance `B#a` will be performed only when it is fully constructed

Answer (score 1):

A will be correctly constructed as all it's fields are final.  The problem you have is there is a race condition on getA() as it is lazy, but not thread safe.  i.e. it is possible for different threads to call this and return different objects.  The objects will be complete and correct but not be the same one which may have been the intent.  Consider the following

```
T1: if (a == null)
T2: if (a == null)
T3: if (a == null)
T1:     a = new A();
T1: return a;
T2:     a = new A();
T2: return a;
T3:     a = new A();
T3: return a;
```

All three threads return a different object.

Comment: I had mentioned about the same 'instance' of B being shared between threads.Would it be the same case then?

Comment: @IUnknown I assumed there was only one instance of `B`.

Comment: The second thread may not see 'a' as null too - as construction of A is not atomic and 'a' is not volatile?

Comment: @IUnknown The problem is that all threads might see `a` as null, even if `a` is volatile.  Making it volatile reduces the time it would seen as `null`.